# How to overcome MemoryError of numpy.unique

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using Numpy version 1.11.1 and have to deal with an two-dimensional array of

```
my_arr.shape = (25000, 25000)
```

All values are integer, and I need a unique list of the arrays values. When using `lst = np.unique(my_arr)` I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    palette = np.unique(arr)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 176, in unique
    ar = np.asanyarray(ar).flatten()
MemoryError
```

My machine has only 8 GB RAM, but I tried it with another machine with 16 GB RAM, and the result is the same. Monitoring the memory and CPU usage doesn't show that the problems are related to RAM or CPU.

In principle, I know the values the array consists of, but what if the input changes... Also, if I want to replace values of the array by another (let's say all 2 by 0), will it need a lot of RAM as well?

Comment: Python 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: Python 2.7.12 as 32-bit

Comment: Sounds like your problem right there. Don't use 32 bit python. Also, try using as small an int as possible; perhaps a single byte per value will do?

Comment: Well, the change to 64 bit I can do. All arrays at hand only consist out of 0, 1, or 2 - just the shape is huge.

Comment: Switching to 64 bit will allow you to use more than 1gb per process. Using my_arr.astype(np.int8) will gain you another factor 4 in memory savings.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Did using 64-bit work for you, or did you have to come up with something else?

Answer (score 0):

Python 32-bit can't access more than 4 GiB RAM (often ~2.5 GiB). The obvious answer would be to use the 64-bit version. If that doesn't work, another solution would be to use `numpy.memmap` and memory-map the array into a file stored on disk.

Comment: I still got a `MemoryError` with 64-bit and using `numpy.memmap`. The array is `float`s with shape `(8465, 103114)`, only slightly bigger than the OP's array. (It comes from a geographic raster.)