# Split numpy array into chunks by maximum size

Tags: python, numpy

I have some *very* large two-dimensional numpy arrays. One data set is 55732 by 257659, which is over 14 billion elements. Because some operations I need to perform throw `MemoryError`s, I would like to try splitting the array up into chunks of a certain size and running them against the chunks. (I can aggregate the results after the operation runs on each piece.) The fact that my problem is `MemoryErrors` means that it's important that I can cap the size of the arrays somehow, rather than split them into a constant number of pieces.

For an example, let's generate a 1009 by 1009 random array:

```
a = numpy.random.choice([1,2,3,4], (1009,1009))
```

My data isn't necessary possible to split evenly, and it's definitely not guaranteed to be splitable by the size I want. So I've chosen 1009 because it's prime.

Let's also say I want them in chunks of no larger than 50 by 50. Since this is just to avoid errors with extremely large arrays, it's okay if the result isn't exact.

How can I split this into the desired chunks?

I'm using Python 3.6 64-bit with numpy 1.14.3 (latest).

### Related

I have seen [this function that uses `reshape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858283/1394393), but it doesn't work if the number of rows and columns doesn't divide the size exactly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14406567/1394393) (among other similar ones) has answers explaining how to split into a certain number of chunks, but this does not explain how to split into a certain size.

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39877999/1394393), since it's actually my exact problem. The answer and comments suggests switching to 64 bit (which I already have) and using `numpy.memmap`. Neither helped.

Comment: I haven't used it myself but did you consider numexpr? It appears to [automatically apply chunking](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) to array operations.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nope. Feel free to post an answer. =) May well be better than mine.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done so that the resulting arrays have shapes slightly less than the desired maximum or so that they have exactly the desired maximum except for some remainder at the end.

The basic logic is to compute the parameters for splitting the array and then use [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to split the array along each axis (or dimension) of the array.

We'll need the `numpy` and `math` modules and the example array:

```
import math
import numpy

a = numpy.random.choice([1,2,3,4], (1009,1009))
```

## Slightly less than max

#### The logic

First store the shape of the final chunk size along each dimension that you want to split it into in a tuple:

```
chunk_shape = (50, 50)
```

`array_split` only splits along one axis (or dimension) or an array at a time. So let's start with just the first axis.

1. Compute the number of sections we need to split the array into:

   ```
   num_sections = math.ceil(a.shape[0] / chunk_shape[0])
   ```

   In our example case, this is 21 (`1009 / 50 = 20.18`).
2. Now split it:

   ```
   first_split = numpy.array_split(a, num_sections, axis=0)
   ```

   This gives us a list of 21 (the number of requested sections) numpy arrays that are split so they are no larger than 50 in the first dimension:

   ```
   print(len(first_split))
   # 21
   print({i.shape for i in first_split})
   # {(48, 1009), (49, 1009)}
   # These are the distinct shapes, so we don't see all 21 separately
   ```

   In this case, they're 48 and 49 along that axis.
3. We can do the same thing to each new array for the second dimension:

   ```
   num_sections = math.ceil(a.shape[1] / chunk_shape[1])
   second_split = [numpy.array_split(a2, num_sections, axis=1) for a2 in first_split]
   ```

   This gives us a list of lists. Each sublist contains numpy arrays of the size we wanted:

   ```
   print(len(second_split))
   # 21
   print({len(i) for i in second_split})
   # {21}
   # All sublists are 21 long
   print({i2.shape for i in second_split for i2 in i})
   # {(48, 49), (49, 48), (48, 48), (49, 49)}
   # Distinct shapes
   ```

#### The full function

We can implement this for arbitrary dimensions using a recursive function:

```
def split_to_approx_shape(a, chunk_shape, start_axis=0):
    if len(chunk_shape) != len(a.shape):
        raise ValueError('chunk length does not match array number of axes')

    if start_axis == len(a.shape):
        return a

    num_sections = math.ceil(a.shape[start_axis] / chunk_shape[start_axis])
    split = numpy.array_split(a, num_sections, axis=start_axis)
    return [split_to_approx_shape(split_a, chunk_shape, start_axis + 1) for split_a in split]
```

We call it like so:

```
full_split = split_to_approx_shape(a, (50,50))
print({i2.shape for i in full_split for i2 in i})
# {(48, 49), (49, 48), (48, 48), (49, 49)}
# Distinct shapes
```

## Exact shapes plus remainder

#### The logic

If we want to be a little fancier and have all the new arrays be *exactly* the specified size except for a trailing leftover array, we can do that by passing a list of indices to split at to `array_split`.

1. First build up the array of indices:

   ```
   axis = 0
   split_indices = [chunk_shape[axis]*(i+1) for i  in range(math.floor(a.shape[axis] / chunk_shape[axis]))]
   ```

   This gives use a list of indices, each 50 from the last:

   ```
   print(split_indices)
   # [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]
   ```
2. Then split:

   ```
   first_split = numpy.array_split(a, split_indices, axis=0)
   print(len(first_split))
   # 21
   print({i.shape for i in first_split})
   # {(9, 1009), (50, 1009)}
   # Distinct shapes, so we don't see all 21 separately
   print((first_split[0].shape, first_split[1].shape, '...', first_split[-2].shape, first_split[-1].shape))
   # ((50, 1009), (50, 1009), '...', (50, 1009), (9, 1009))
   ```
3. And then again for the second axis:

   ```
   axis = 1
   split_indices = [chunk_shape[axis]*(i+1) for i  in range(math.floor(a.shape[axis] / chunk_shape[axis]))]
   second_split = [numpy.array_split(a2, split_indices, axis=1) for a2 in first_split]
   print({i2.shape for i in second_split for i2 in i})
   # {(9, 50), (9, 9), (50, 9), (50, 50)}
   ```

#### The full function

Adapting the recursive function:

```
def split_to_shape(a, chunk_shape, start_axis=0):
    if len(chunk_shape) != len(a.shape):
        raise ValueError('chunk length does not match array number of axes')

    if start_axis == len(a.shape):
        return a

    split_indices = [
        chunk_shape[start_axis]*(i+1)
        for i in range(math.floor(a.shape[start_axis] / chunk_shape[start_axis]))
    ]
    split = numpy.array_split(a, split_indices, axis=start_axis)
    return [split_to_shape(split_a, chunk_shape, start_axis + 1) for split_a in split]
```

And we call it exactly the same way:

```
full_split = split_to_shape(a, (50,50))
print({i2.shape for i in full_split for i2 in i})
# {(9, 50), (9, 9), (50, 9), (50, 50)}
# Distinct shapes
```

## Extra Notes

#### Performance

These functions seem to be quite fast. I was able to split up my example array (with over 14 billion elements) into 1000 by 1000 shaped pieces (resulting in over 14000 new arrays) in under 0.05 seconds with either function:

```
print('Building test array')
a = numpy.random.randint(4, size=(55000, 250000), dtype='uint8')
chunks = (1000, 1000)
numtests = 1000
print('Running {} tests'.format(numtests))
print('split_to_approx_shape: {} seconds'.format(timeit.timeit(lambda: split_to_approx_shape(a, chunks), number=numtests) / numtests))
print('split_to_shape: {} seconds'.format(timeit.timeit(lambda: split_to_shape(a, chunks), number=numtests) / numtests))
```

Output:

```
Building test array
Running 1000 tests
split_to_approx_shape: 0.035109398348040485 seconds
split_to_shape: 0.03113800323300747 seconds
```

I did not test speed with higher dimension arrays.

#### Shapes smaller than the max

These functions both work properly if the size of any dimension is less than the specified maximum. This requires no special logic.

Comment: Wonderful answer!  I just want to point out that `np.block(full_split)` reassembles the original array.

Answer (score 3):

As I don't know how your data is generated or will be processed, I can suggest two approaches:

## **Enable the use of numpy's reshape**

Pad the array to allow reshaping it into your chunk dimensions. Simply pad with zeros, such that each `(axis_size % chunk_size) == 0`. The `chunk_size` could be different for each axis.

Padding a multidimensional array like this creates a (slightly bigger) copy. To avoid the copy, 'cut out' the biggest chunkable array, reshape it and process the left over borders separately.

Depending on how your data needs to be processed, this could be very impractical.

## **Use a list comp**

I think there are more simple / readable versions of the split implementation. Either using `numpy.split()` or just fancy indexing.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1009)

chunk_size = 50

%timeit np.split(a, range(chunk_size, a.shape[0], chunk_size))
%timeit [a[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, a.shape[0], chunk_size)]
```

shows that the list comp is ~3x as fast while returning the same result:

```
36.8 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
10.4 µs ± 2.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I guess the speedup of the list comprehension should directly translate into higher dimensional arrays. [numpy's implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.2/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L431-L483) of array_split does basically that, but additionally allows chunking in arbitrary axes. However the list comp could be extended to do that, too.

Answer (score -1):

By simply using `np.array_split` and ceiling division we can do this relatively easily.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

max_size = 15
test = np.arrange(101)

result = np.array_split(test, (len(test) + (max_size -1) ) // max_size)
```

Comment: This approach is wrong since it suffers when len(test) and max size are close numbers. For example with len(test) = 11 , max size = 10, this returns 1 instead of 2.  
This could be solved by using  result = np.array_split(test, (len(test) + (max_size -1) ) // max_size), which returns the result for ceiling division  instead of floor division.

Comment: I might have been confused about what split means, where if you split something once, it would produce 2 parts. However, the array_split behavior wasn't the same as my intuition. I changed it to have it as a ceiling instead of a floor, thanks!